# The form cannot run the specified query. The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

We have admin-approved InfoPath 2010 form with code deployed on Sharepoint 2010. The form has a few REST data connections which execute on form load. One user keeps getting this error when opening form:

> XML data that is required for this form to function correctly cannot be found. An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server. Log ID:5566

Correlation ID gives these errors in Sharepoint log:

> Data adapter failed during OnLoad: The form cannot run the specified query. The following query failed: REST ... Type: DataAdapterException, Exception Message: The form cannot run the specified query. The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

When the user tries to open the same form after a few seconds everything works as expected. I couldn't reproduce the issue. Does anyone have any clue what could be the reason for this? Thank you.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/af109d85-4d1c-419a-961d-130b7516572b/data-adapter-failed-during-onload-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-503-server-unavailable?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

Comment: Recent issue is high cpu of 100% for w3wp.exe and top requests for worker process are REST data connections from infopath form.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to resolve the issue:

```
$f = Get-SPInfoPathFormsService 
$f.Properties.Add("AllowEventPropagation", $false) 
$f.Update()
```

Reference link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2984138/forms-timeout-or-take-a-long-time-to-open-in-infopath-2010-or-infopath